# PHP Sessions Losing Half on Redirect

Tags: php, function, session, redirect, header

I have been working on this for awhile and can't seem to pin it down. Sessions are working I have session_start() at the top of each page that I access or set sessions.

First off I started with three sessions variables $_SESSION['id'], $_SESSION['user'] and $_SESSION['start'] to my login script and everything was working fine. I added two more sessions $_SESSION['patron'] and $_SESSION['business'].

```
$_SESSION['user'] = $user_info['email'];
$_SESSION['id'] =   $user_info['id'];
$_SESSION['patron'] = $user_info['patron'];
$_SESSION['business'] = $user_info['business'];
$_SESSION['start'] = time();
redirect_to('../page.php');
```

All sessions are set after login script is run and redirected fine, but I lose some of them when I redirect again leaving just the $_SESSION['user'], $_SESSION['start'] and $_SESSION['id'] sessions still set. I don't understand why only some are still set and the others are lost.

Another issue is that I changed the session $_SESSION['start'] name to $_SESSION['time'] and now that session is lost when I redirect after my login script has run.

Here is my redirect script:

```
function redirect_to($location = NULL) {
     if($location != NULL) {
        define('URL', 'http://www.website.com/');
          header('Location: ' .URL. $location);
        exit();
     }
}
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: are you using output buffers? Also show your login script

Comment: session_start, on all pages?

Comment: Are your scripts in different subdirectories of the website?

Comment: You can try to write a new separated script, that uses a session and redirects to itself or another script, that shows you all the session variables. If it works, you need to check all the code that reuse your session inside your application. Something like this: `session_start(); if(isset($_GET['redirected']){var_dump($_SESSION;} else { $_SESSION=$_GET; header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?redirect=1');}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!!!

I've been working on this project for too long...I forgot that I had a function that purges sessions. It unsets sessions created by form submissions. I have an array that has session names to ignore and I left these out of it. So every time a page is refreshed, it unsets those sessions. I am so sorry for wasting your time. I completely forgot about it. I worked on that for about two hours....Lame.